# Rename entries in EFI

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

I have two disks with EFI boot enabled.

Each of disks have its own Debian installed but with different version. When booting up it is hard to choose one - both have same label.
In efibootmgr it looks like this

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0001
Boot0000* debian    HD(2,MBR,0x985ae8ad,0x6e9df800,0x1dc800)/File(\EFI\DEBIAN\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........k.W.D.S.1.0.0.T.3.X.H.C.-.0.0.S.J.G.0....................A............................D.D..n........Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.9.1.6.7.2.8.0.0.1.9.6........BO..NO........k.W.D.S.1.0.0.T.1.X.0.E.-.0.0.A.F.Y.0....................A............................DJI..@........Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.1.3.9.D.Y.4.5.6.8.1.1........BO..NO........o.K.I.N.G.S.T.O.N. .S.E.D.C.5.0.0.R.3.8.4.0.G....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.5.2.0.B.6.6.7.3.8.C.C.E.7.E.8. . . . ........BO..NO........o.P.L.E.X.T.O.R. .P.X.-.1.2.8.M.5.P.r.o....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.P.3.2.0.5.0.1.9.1.2.9. . . . . . . . ........BO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.6.0. .E.V.O. .2.5.0.G.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.S.J.Y.B.N.K.0.0.3.9.4.2.1. .K. . . . ........BO..NO........o.C.r.u.c.i.a.l._.C.T.2.5.6.M.X.1.0.0.S.S.D.1....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . .4.1.7.3.D.0.D.2.B.3.7.4........BO
Boot0002* debian    HD(1,MBR,0xc767e071,0x800,0x200000)/File(\EFI\DEBIAN\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
#
```

How can I rename one?
Why is only one disk listed here as "Hard Drive" not two of them ?

Comment: Can be done manually using `man efibootmgr`

Comment: There is no rename option here

Comment: Yeah, you need to remove and add it back.